# How to prepend a backslash using clojure.string/replace

Tags: regex, string, clojure

I am trying to use `clojure.string/replace` to escape certain characters like asterisks and backticks with backslashes (like `ex*mple` -> `ex\*mple`), but I cannot make sense of the function's own escaping rules:

If I try `` (cs/replace "ex*mple" #"[\*`]" "\\$0") ``, it treats the `$0` literally and returns `ex$0mple`.

If I try `` (cs/replace "ex*mple" #"[\*`]" "\\\\$0") `` it adds two slashes: `ex\\*mple`.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: It seems second approach is the right one but the reason you see double escapes is just because it is how to show a literal backslash.

Comment: Are you trying to escape a string so you can use it as a regex pattern?

Comment: No, i'm trying to escape some of the characters from the Markdown subset used by Telegram.

Comment: @revo - you are right of course. I should have checked more thoroughly before asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second approach, `` (cs/replace "ex*mple" #"[\*`]" "\\\\$0") ``, is correct. The reason you see two backslashes in the result is because that's how Clojure shows single backslashes in strings. If you print `"ex\\*mple"`, you'll see `ex\*mple`.

Clojure uses backslash as an escape character in strings, so backslashes themselves have to be escaped. `ex\*mple` is not a valid string in Clojure because `\*` is an unsupported escape character.